# Xcode swift 2.2 Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I can not build, before upgrading to Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2 everything was OK, now It throw several mistakes I've debugged and corrected most of them, but there is one in particular that tells me nothing more than this:

> Command failed due to signal: Killed 9

This is what shown in the report navigator details :

> CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/API.swift cd
>   /Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/ReservaTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CorrespondenciaChooseParamsViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/AbogadoTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/AbogadoNuevoViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/FieldsEntities.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/SidebarMenuViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/MensajeFilterViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/RecadoViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/LoginViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/NewMessageViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/FacturaTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/AbogadoFilterViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/HomeViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/FacturaDetailViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/RecadoTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/FeedbackViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/DateViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CorrespondenciaTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/MensajeDetailViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/HistorialReservaFilterViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CdrTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/ReservaCocheraViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CorrespondenciaViewController.swift" -primary-file
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/API.swift" "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/EmpresaEntity.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/RecadoChooseParamsViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/ConversationViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/ReservaTableViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/MensajeViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/ReservasDisponiblesTableViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/MensajeTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/Empresa.swift" "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/Helpers.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/ConversarionTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CdrViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/HorasExtrasViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/CdrFiltersViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/HistorialReservaViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/Recurso.swift" "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/AbogadoViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/AppDelegate.swift" "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/FacturaFiltersViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/FacturaViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/AuditorioViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/HistorialReservaTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros
>   Virtuales/RecursoEntity.swift" "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros
>   Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/EmpresaViewController.swift" -target
>   i386-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales" -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/Centros Virtuales-Bridging-Header.h"
>   -module-cache-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/CVirtuales-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/CVirtuales-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/CVirtuales-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/CVirtuales-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -Xcc -I/Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/oscarsith/xdodeProyects/Centros Virtuales"
>   -emit-module-doc-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name CVirtuales -emit-module-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/oscarsith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CVirtuales-esdsxwvvcbarqjfetgncfnlwuqns/Build/Intermediates/CVirtuales.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CVirtuales.build/Objects-normal/i386/API.o

Comment: for swift 3 this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632975/xcode-8-swift-3-command-failed-due-to-signal-killed-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clean your build folder `Cmd+Shift+Option+K`, choose another simulator available in your Xcode then build it again.
Error here: seems like missing simulator

```
...-target i386-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -I
```